# open many file in one time and each store as one dataframe

Tags: r

I have many data in one folder

```
data=list.files(path="D:/result")
```

data

```
> > [1] "CNVWorkShop (1).txt" "e17 result.txt"       [3] "E17new result.txt"   "E18 NEW RESULT.txt" 
> 
>  [5] "e18result.txt"       "l15 new result.txt"    [7] "l15
> result.txt"      "L22NEW RESULT.txt"    [9] "L51 NEW RESULT.txt" 
> "l51result.txt"       [11] "L54 NEW RESULT.txt"  "L54result.txt"      
> [13] "PennCNV.txt"         "s40 new result.txt"
```

I want to read many file in one time and store each file as each dataframe

```
a=paste("watto",1:14,sep="")
```

This things below I do but it's not work

```
for(i in 1 :length(data)){
  a[i]=read.table(file=paste("D:/result/",data[i],sep=""),header=T,sep="\t") 
}
```

and it's show the warning  message and not give me a result

```
> Warning message:
In a[1] = read.table(file = paste("D:/result/", data[1], sep = ""),  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

The result which I want is

```
> data from watto1 come from CNVWorkShop (1).txt 
> data from watto2 come from e17 result.txt
```

How I should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  a  <- lapply(data, function(x) read.table(file=paste0("D:/result/",x),
    header=TRUE, sep="\t") )
```

You're getting the error message because of R's subsetting rules. When you assign with single brackets `a[1] <-`, R expects a replacement by something of the same length 1. For `a[c(1,2)] <-` R accepts replacement values of length 2, and so on. Your data frame has length (being number of columns) greater than 1 and so is being rejected.

You could do this instead to specify that you are replacing the list element (note the double-brackets:

```
for(i in 1 :length(data)){
  a[[i]]=read.table(file=paste("D:/result/",data[i],sep=""),
    header=TRUE,sep="\t") 
}
```

However, this is not very R-like syntax. Iterative tasks that do not rely on recursion can be performed via the `lapply` family of functions.

Comment: thanks for your help but I'm very new in R. Could you explain more about paste0  function. What is x represent. However it still have an error message when run you code "In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'D:/result/ ': Permission denied"   @Blue Magister

Comment: `paste0` is `paste` with default `sep = ''`. `lapply` says to perform the following function on each member of `data`. Try something like `lapply(1:5,function(x) x^2)` to see what happens. If you're getting that error then there may be an entry in `data` that's just the blank string `""`. Can you check?